# NTILE SQL bucket ONLY 4 matches not 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

Is there a way for the SQL NTILE() function to group only the max input value? For example, when I use NTILE(4) I don't want the function to group values that have 2 or 3 matches, only the ones that have 4 matches.

I'm having a hard time doing this.

My data set looks like this

```
id timetraveled
1  5
1  5
1  5
1  5
2  6
2  6
```

I'm expecting NTILE(4) to return the following:

```
ntile id timetraveled
1     1  5
2     1  5 
3     1  5
4     1  5
1     2  6
1     2  6
```

but instead it will give me:

```
ntile id timetraveled
1     1  5
2     1  5 
3     1  5
4     1  5
1     2  6
*2*   2  6
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ntile()`.  You can calculate your own:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum <= 0.25 * cnt then 1
             when seqnum <= 0.50 * cnt then 2
             when seqnum <= 0.75 * cnt then 3
             else 4
        end) as ntile,
       floor(1 + ((seqnum - 1) * 4 / cnt)) as ntile_2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timetravelled) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t;
```

This has two different methods for calculating the "ntile" value that you want.

You could also use `percentile()` (or a related function) and do arithmetic on that.  I prefer to be explicit about the calculation.